# Does a fiber product of a group $G$ by itself have $G$ as a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, fibre-product

Consider a group $G$ and a fiber product of the form $G\times_H G$. Is it true that such fiber product always have a subgroup isomorphic to $G$?

I'm tempted to say "Yes" because it's true if you consider the extremal cases $H=G$ and $H=\{e\}$. But I have no idea how to prove it in the general case. Thank you!

*Edit by Derek Holt*: Let me attempt to state the problem more explicitly.

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and let $\phi_1,\phi_2:G \to H$ be surjective homomorphisms.

Is it always true that the subgroup $\{ (g_1,g_2) : \phi_1(g_1) = \phi_2(g_2) \}$ of $G \times G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: What about the diagonal subgroup $\{(g,g) \mid g \in G \}$?

Comment: It would be less clear if you used two different surjective morphisms $G \to H$ to construct the fiber product.

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt . I meant that there exists at least one such morphism. So your "less clear" case is exactly the point of my question. Let me edit my question to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: Your edit did not make this more clear.

Comment: If you are not assuming that and that is actually an important point then making it clear would be to *emphasize* it somehow. While the notation $G\times_H G$ certainly does not imply that the two maps are the same, they usually are. It is you who are asking for help: make it easy for people to help you by being as explicit about what you are asking. Or not, it is up to you and how much you want people to help you

Comment: Since I find it interesting, I have attempted to clarify the question. I hope that is what you meant! I would guess that the answer is no, but I have not been able to think of a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez for your interest in my question, and pointing out how it could be improved.

Comment: Thank you very much for you edit and your interest @DerekHolt ! I will update the question if I find the answer.

Comment: @user1729 But the maps $G \to H$ are required to be surjective. (I think that's a standard requirement for a fiber product.)

Comment: @DerekHolt That's exactly what I was missing, thanks!